# unable to open nextcloud homepage on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nextcloud

I tried to do a simple deployment of nextcloud on a k8s cluster hosted using minikube on my local machine for learning purposes. This deployment doesn't have any database/storage attached to it. I'm simply looking to open the nextcloud homepage on my local machine. However, I am unable to do so. Here are my yamls.

Deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nextcloud-deployment
  labels:
    app: nextcloud
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nextcloud
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nextcloud
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nextcloud
        image: nextcloud:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: nextcloud-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nextcloud
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30000
```

I can see that it is up and running, however when i navigate to localhost:30000, i see that the page is unavailable. How do i begin to diagnose the issue?

This was the output of `kubectl get service`:

```
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes          ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          3d5h
nextcloud-service   LoadBalancer   10.104.40.61   <pending>     8000:30000/TCP   23m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `minikube service nextcloud-service` and it will open it for you.